# Issue running atmosphere 2.4.0 on tomcat 7.0.42

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, websocket, atmosphere

Following the example laid out here: http://angularjstutorial.blogspot.ca/2013/10/atmosphere-and-angularjs.html#.VeewkNwrJhG

I managed to make the websocket run on jetty. However, running the exact same thing on tomcat 7.0.42 failed. Below is the exception snippet:

> 17:47:27.173 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed WebSocketProtocol
>   org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol  17:47:27.188
>   [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.a.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver -
>   **Failed to create AsyncSupport class**: class
>   org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport, error: {}
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_40]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_40]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_40]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_40]    at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:234)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:297)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:283)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:2057)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:911)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:835)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.configureFramework(AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.java:74)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:83)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:79)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:74)
>   [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.42]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.42]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.42]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.42]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.42]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.42]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.42]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.42]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_40]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [na:1.7.0_40]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [na:1.7.0_40]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [na:1.7.0_40]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer is null. Make sure you are
>   using 1.7+ and your server has websocket support enabled  at
>   org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:53)
>   ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:40)
>   ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC4.jar:2.4.0-RC4]     ... 26 common frames
>   omitted 17:47:27.188 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN 
>   o.a.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver - Found multiple containers,
>   please specify which one to use:
>   org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport,
>   org.atmosphere.container.TomcatCometSupport,  until you do, Atmosphere
>   will use:class org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport
>   17:47:27.204 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installing Default
>   AtmosphereInterceptors 17:47:27.204 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -
>     org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support

I changed the jdk from 6, to 7, to 8 and the exception remains.

Has anyone any idea how to resolve this?